# How to handle hyperparameter tuning for LSTM with early stopping?

Tags: validation, neural-network, lstm, cross-validation

I am looking for advice on the best practice to determine hyperparameters for my LSTM model. I have time series data that I have divided into train and test sets. I was planning to use an expanding walk forward cross validation scheme on my train set to determine the hyperparameters and then use the test to obtain a final evaluation score. However, I am confused as to how to use the early stopping with this setup. Should I:

1. **At each CV iteration use the test fold as a validation set to determine how many epochs to train for with early stopping?** This potentially will skew the CV score based on how much the model overfits the test fold at each CV iteration.
2. **Just preset the number of epochs for each fold and not use early stopping?** - due to the different number of data points in each fold, this may not make sense.

Also if I do use CV, how do I determine my early stopping rounds for the final model (without using the test set)?

Would I be better off just dividing my data into a train/val/test split and tuning both hyperparameters and early stopping on the validation set?

Thank you!